# Google Analytics is not receiving Consent Signals (aparrently)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have recently integrated the new(ish) Google Consent Mode into our Website and into Google Tag Manager. Using Google Tag Manager in preview mode, I can verify that the Consent is both updated correctly on accepting the cookie banner, as well as having the defaults set according to the user's consent while changing pages.

[image]

However, after more than a week Google Analytics still claims, that it does not receive any Consent Signals.

[image]

I have checked and it looks to me, like the events all get tracked with consent signals (our provider for the website plugin seems to have chosen to set the matching defaults, instead of updating the consents on every page). Though the `gcd` parameter is separated by `3` instead of `1`:

```json
{
  "v": 2,
  "gcs": "G111",
  "gcd": "13t3t3t3t5",
  ...
}
```

Which looks to me like `Both Google Ads and Google Analytics have consent` and `All consent states are granted by default`. Anything I'm missing here?

---

## Update

Nevermind, Apparently it took Analytics 2 weeks to realize it was receiving Consent signals. I havent't changed anything since implementing them,and now Analytics has stopped complaining. But maybe there was a reason for this I just haven't found.